# Run gradle from perl script

Tags: android, linux, perl, gradle, server

I'm trying to launch a gradle andrpod apk build from a perl script on the server. I tried different solutions, like:

```
my $path = Cwd::cwd();
$build_output = `cd $appFolder && ./gradlew assembleRelease | cd $path`;
```

I tried using system and open with a pipe, but the result is the same.

When I try to add this to my existing script, it doesn't wait for the gradle build to start.
All other calls to system commands work fine, it's just the gradle build that appears to quit immediately.

Any ideas on what might be different on the gradle call?

**EDIT**:

redirecting STDERROR and running the following command:

```
my $build_output = `cd $appFolder && pwd && ./gradlew assembleRelease 2>&1`;
my $err = $? >> 8;
if ($?) {
    print LOG "\n\n BUILD ERROR: \n\n$err\n$build_output\n";
} else {
    print LOG "\n\n BUILD OUTPUT: \n\n$build_output\n";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
BUILD ERROR: 
/var/www/html/upload/myApp
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcssdffbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcssdffbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:49)
    ... 3 more
```

So I need to understand why it's looking for .gradle/ folder inside /var/www instead of the folder I chdir into. I tried setting GRADLE_USER_HOME variable to /usr/local/gradle but it still searches for /var/www/.gradle/ .

**SOLVED**

The reason why it was looking for .gradle in/var/www is because the script is launched by an apache user. Moving the folder there and granting access solved the problem.

Comment: You don't need to `chdir` back again - all the shell invocations open a subshell and you cannot affect the parent's environment (or cwd) from a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `chdir` back again - all the shell invocations open a subshell and you cannot affect the parent's environment (or cwd) from a subshell.

Also, even if you did want to do that, you'd want `||` rather than `|` because otherwise you're piping the output to 'cd' which is almost certainly not what you want to do.

So:

```
$build_output = `cd $appFolder && ./gradlew assembleRelease`;
```

Should do the right thing.

If it doesn't, the only thing I can think of is:

- It's expecting `STDIN` to be connected. (Workarounds include `IPC::Open2`).
- It's trying to open a window, and there's no window manager available.

EDIT

redirecting STDERROR and running the following command:

```
my $build_output = `cd $appFolder && pwd && ./gradlew assembleRelease 2>&1`;
my $err = $? >> 8;
if ($?) {
    print LOG "\n\n BUILD ERROR: \n\n$err\n$build_output\n";
} else {
    print LOG "\n\n BUILD OUTPUT: \n\n$build_output\n";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
BUILD ERROR: 
/var/www/html/upload/myApp
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcssdffbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcssdffbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:49)
    ... 3 more
```

So I need to understand why it's looking for .gradle/ folder inside /var/www instead of the folder I chdir into. It may be related to the GRADLE_USER_HOME variable.

Comment: thanks for the hint, the pipe and the second cd are indeed unnecessary, but the result is still the same. the gradle build doesn't ask for any user input so I don't think it could be expecting STDIN, and the command runs on the shell without opening windows.

Comment: In which case I'd try testing `$?` to see the return code. I assume that `$appFolder` is an absolute path, or one that's 'beneath' the cwd?

Comment: sorry, I edited your comment instead of my original one.